# Google Maps Controls - How to update continuously

Tags: javascript, google-maps, controls

I would like to create a control on a google map and then update it with the lat long coordinates when the user clicks (or better drags) on the map.
I first created a div element, and then inside the eventlistener of 'click' I am removing and replacing the child:

```
var coordDiv = document.createElement("div");
var tmp = document.createTextNode(" ");
coordDiv.appendChild(tmp);
coordDiv.index = 0;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
        var lon = event.latLng.lng();

        var text = document.createTextNode(p.x.toFixed(2) + "m " + p.y.toFixed(2) + "m");
        coordDiv.removeChild(tmp);
        coordDiv.appendChild(text);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(coordDiv);
        tmp = text;    
});
```

The problem are 2:

1. the div moves on the map: it doesnt stay on the same place (bottom-right) but it moves upwards at each click
2. I actually would like to have a 'dragstart' event listener but it cannot see the lat long coordinates
   Thanks for your help!

Comment: I solved the first problem in this way: I check if the div element exist (using getElementById) and then if it already exists I remove it and I recreate it.. I don't know if this is a nice way to do it but at least it works :) The second problem remains.. The thing is that the 'dragstart' eventlistener doesn't have a event function from which I can get the lat and long.. instead with 'click' I have function(event) and I can do event.latLng.lat()...

Comment: You could use the mousemove event to update lat & long values. Once you've created the div update its html content with javascript or jquery.

Comment: Yes but I am working on android.. I have to use some touch or drag events...